# Laravel 5 different log levels for development and production

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5, monolog

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and trying to set different logging logic for a development and production environment.

Throughout my application I am using the `Log` facade with most of the following different methods:

```
Log::emergency($error);
Log::alert($error);
Log::critical($error);
Log::error($error);
Log::warning($error);
Log::notice($error);
Log::info($error);
Log::debug($error);
```

However, in my production environment, I would like to only log anything that is an `Error`, `Critical`, `Alert` or `Emergency` priority and ignore log requests with lower priority.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation or by exploring the code (both `Log` facade and the `Monolog` class).

My current thought is to create a custom wrapper around the Log facade that simply checks the environment and ignores anything below 400 (Monolog level for Error). Basically I would create a threshold variable in the environment file and anything below it will simply not be logged to the files.

Before I do so, I wanted to ask the community if there is an existing method/configuration for that which I could use, so that I don't re-invent the wheel.

If not - what would be the best approach?

Comment: Which logger are you using? "single", "daily", "syslog" or "errorlog"? Unfortunately solution depends on the logger used.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I'm using `Daily`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/briceburg/77e97d90b1073c7622cb) shows a more comfortable answer, as is not dependent on the 
chosen handler.

I'm just providing the essential part in an answer here in case the above link gets deleted in some time.

In the AppServiceProviders' register method:

```
/**
* Register any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function register()
{
    //
    $monolog = Log::getMonolog();
    foreach($monolog->getHandlers() as $handler) {
      $handler->setLevel(Config::get('app.log-level'));
    }
}
```

Then just add an additional key to your config/app.php:

```
'log-level' => 'info', // or whatever minimum log level you would like.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to your **AppServiceProvider::register()**:

```
$this->app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
  $monolog->pushHandler(
    $handler = new RotatingFileHandler(
       $this->app->storagePath() . '/logs/laravel.log',
       $this->app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5),
       $this->app->make('config')->get('app.level', 'debug')
     )
  );

  $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
});
```

This recreates the logic that **Laravel** does when setting up the **daily** handler, but adds passing level to the handler.

You can set your minimum logging level by setting **level** value in your **config/app.php**:

```
'level' => 'debug', //debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency
```

This is a bit of a workaround and each type of handler would need to be set up separately. I'm currently working on a pull-request to **Laravel** that would add setting minimum debug level from the config file without writing a line of code in your **AppServiceProvider**.

The code above hasn't been tested, so let me know if you see any typos or something doesn't work properly and I'll be more than happy to make that work for you.

Comment: There is an issue with L5 logging (on Linux) in that, if you run `artisan` from the command line **not** as the *web user*, a log file could be created that cannot be written to by the *web server*. I've filed a pull request fixing the issue but was told to use `configureMonologUsing()` instead.

So be aware and `chmod` your log files in there too. ;)