# How to disable displaying of application log messages on console while phpunit tests are running?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am writing tests for a Laravel application, specifically for a process which writes a lot of log messages on console.

e.g.

```
Log::info('Process starts', [
    'process_name' => 'product_import',
    'data' => // a huge text containing json_encode of the given message object
]
```

When I run phpunit, I see all these annoying log messages on console. Is there a way to disable or somehow stop these log messages?

Answer (score 2):

You can set environment variables in your `phpunit.xml` file.

If you increase the log level to notice it should prevent info notices from being output

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="APP_LOG_LEVEL" value="notice"/>
</php>
```

If you're using Laravel 5.2 or older, there is no `APP_LOG_LEVEL` env variable,
 but you can sill [introduce your own env variable and configure Monolog in your app service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084132/3250005).

Comment: The application is based on Laravel 5.1. I don't think this version has a config for application log level :(

Comment: @ArminSam That env variable was introduced in 5.3 I believe. This solution can still work, but you would need to introduce your own env variable and configure Monolog in your app service provider.

Answer (score 1):

You could mock the `Log` facade if you want to turn off login in some specified test methods or classes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mocking-facades

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old issue but in my case (Laravel 8, PHP 7.4) this was being caused by the fact I had an environment variable set

```
# /.env

LOG_CHANNEL=stack`
```

referring to a logging configuration that used the `single` and `stderr` channels...

```
# /config/logging.php

'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['single', 'stderr'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],
```

`stderr` was my issue, after removing this I no longer saw application log output in my phpunit tests