# Multiple level Laravel log

Tags: php, laravel, logging

Is there a way to make a unique Laravel channel log in determined multiple levels? Something like that:

```php
// Throw critical, error and debug to 'single' channel

'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel-'.date('Y-m-d').'.log'),
    'level' => ['critical', 'error', 'debug']
],
```

Comment: isn't this what the Stack driver already does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 different log levels for development and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168163/laravel-5-different-log-levels-for-development-and-production)

Comment: Do you mean splitting the log file for each level?

Comment: @Jerodev i want a log channel to work with a determined set of channels, for example, single channel only logs what happens related to error, critical and debug events.